# insert script to iframe in webview in electron

Tags: iframe, webview

I have a project by using electron and use webview to wrap a website, I want to insert some script to the iframe in the webview, what can I do?

I have try with code like this, but it seems useless;

```
<webview
  partition="persist:webview"
  plugins
  ref="webview"   
  :class="isActive ? 'active' : 'hidden'"
  :useragent="userAgent"
  nodeintegration
  nodeintegrationinsubframes
  :preload="preloadUrl"
></webview>
```